# Defining command \file#1 and use it with \input command, and counter \thefile#1

Tags: input, xstring

I would like to define a command as `\file#1` in order to use it with `\input{\file#1}`, where `#1` is a entry given, as well as counter `\thefile#1`

The MWE is the next code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\fileone}{testfile}
\newcommand{\file}[2]{%
\IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
    {one}{%
        \newcounter{file#1}\setcounter{file#1}{#2}\thefileone
        \input{\fileone}
        }
}}

\begin{document}
Hello, \file{one}{20}
\commandone
\end{document}
```

and the file `testfile.tex` has `\commandone` definined as
`\newcommand{\commandone}{This a test in file "\fileone"}`.

I would like to replace the word "one" by "#1" in order to use `\thefile#1` and `\input{\file#1}` on definition of `\file`.

Comment: What's the purpose of defining a new counter?

Comment: I don't understand the whole purpose of this! Code golfing? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a new counter on the fly is not always a good idea, but this works:

Generating command sequences from other macros or tokens is done with `\csname file#1\endcsname`, for example, the same for the counter output `\csname the#1\endcsname`.

I suggest to use `\InputIfFileExists{}{}{}` instead of `\input{...}` only

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\fileone}{testfile}

\newcommand{\filethree}{otherfile}

\begin{filecontents}{\filethree.tex}
\newcommand{\commandthree}{This a test command in file "otherfile"}
\end{filecontents}



\newcommand{\file}[2]{%
  \newcounter{file#1}\setcounter{file#1}{#2}\csname thefile#1\endcsname%
  \InputIfFileExists{\csname file#1\endcsname}{}{}%
}


\begin{document}
Hello, \file{one}{20}
\commandone

Now: \file{three}{1000}

\commandthree
\end{document}
```

[image]